# Creating Time Series in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I need a little help with following with APACHE Pig script:

Consider following dataset:

ID  | NAME | CREATED DATE
123 | ABC  | 2014-12-15 00:00:00.000

123 | ABC  | 2014-12-25 00:00:00.000

123 | DEF  | 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000

123 | ABC  | 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000

123 | DEF  | 2015-02-16 00:00:00.000

In above data, to any specific ID, different NAME can be assigned and reassigned, example above ID: 123 has 2 names assigned to it: ABC, DEF
Here the requirement it to create a kind of time series of ID and NAME based on 2 created date and create a start date and end date.
Just to clarify a little more, I want all sequence of when an ID is assigned to a particular name and what is its start date and end date. 
Following is an output I expect:

ID  | NAME | START DATE              | END DATE

123 | ABC  | 2014-12-15 00:00:00.000 | 2014-12-25 00:00:00.000

123 | DEF  | 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000

123 | ABC  | 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 2015-02-16 00:00:00.000

123 | ABC  | 2015-02-16 00:00:00.000 |

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding about your problem, i created a script.

A = load 'pigexpr.txt'   USING PigStorage('|') as (id1, name1,cdate1);

B = load 'pigexpr.txt'   USING PigStorage('|') as (id, name,cdate);

ranked = rank A;

rankb = rank B;

B1 = Filter rankb by (rank_B > 1) ;

rankb1 = rank B1;

C = join ranked BY rank_A, rankb1 BY rank_B1;

D = foreach C  generate ranked::id1,ranked::name1,ranked::cdate1,rankb1::cdate;

dump D;